Vent-like object between truck cab and box
2010 Silverado 1500
What is this black plastic part between the truck cab and the truck box?

Inside the cab, beneath the bottom corners of the rear window; one on each side:

Is it a vent to let fresh air in or moisture out? Or a way to let air pressure escape when closing doors?

It is the cab vent. When you turn on the ventilation system outside air is drawn in at the base of the windshield. To draw in outside air some of the cabin air has to be removed via the vent panels.
